# Upgrade Vuetify 1.5 data table to 2.0: custom columns, row hower and on-row-click-event

Tags: vuetify.js

data table changed significantly in vuetify 2.0, please find below the working code for vuetify 1.5:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  class="elevation-1"
  :rows-per-page-items="[10, 25, 50]"
>
  <template v-slot:items="props">
    <tr @click="selectRow(props.item)" :class="{'primary': props.item.vid===selectedItemId}">
      <td>
        <a v-bind:href="props.item.webpage_url" target="_blank">{{ props.item.title }}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ props.item.upload_date }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.uploader }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.view_count }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.like_count }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.dislike_count }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.score }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.duration }}</td>
      <td><router-link :to="{ path: '/vidcc', name:'vidcc', params: { vid: props.item.vid }}" target="_blank">cc</router-link></td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I managed to replace the first column with a custom v-slot. Any examples regarding the on-lick and selected formatting highly appreciated. My Vuetify 2.0 try outs:

```
   <v-data-table
        dense
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        class="elevation-1"
        :footer-props="{
          'items-per-page-options': [10, 25, 50],
        }"
      >
        <template v-slot:[`item.title`]="{ item }">
          <a target="_blank" :href="item.webpage_url">
            {{ item.title }}
          </a>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-data>
          <router-link :to="{ path: '/vidcc', name:'vidcc', params: { vid: item.vid }}" target="_blank">cc</router-link>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

For now I ended up rendering every td manually:

```
<v-data-table
        dense
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        class="elevation-1"
        :footer-props="{
          'items-per-page-options': [10, 25, 50],
        }"
        @click:row="selectRow"
      >
        <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
        <tbody>
        <tr @click="selectRow(item)" :class="{'primary': item.vid===selectedItemId}" v-for="(item) in items" :key="item.vid">
          <td class="text-start"><a target="_blank" :href="item.webpage_url" :ref="'element' + item.vid" >{{ item.title }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ item.upload_date }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.uploader }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.view_count }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.like_count }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.dislike_count }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.duration }}</td>
          <td><router-link :to="{ path: '/vidcc', name:'vidcc', params: { vid: item.vid }}" target="_blank">cc</router-link></td>
        </tr></tbody>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```